# How to write sql query for this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My table looks like this:

```
id  staus
 1    p
 1    p
 1    c
 2    p
 2    c
```

I need to produce counts of rows with the statuses of `'p'` and `'c'` for each `id`, so the result I expect should look like this:

```
id  p  c
 1  2  1    <-- id 1 has two rows with 'p' and one row with 'c'
 2  1  1    <-- id 2 has one row with 'p' and one row with 'c'
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: It also helps to provide the table definitions.

Comment: [`PIVOT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT
    id
,   SUM (CASE STATUS WHEN 'p' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as p
,   SUM (CASE STATUS WHEN 'c' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as c
FROM my_table
GROUP BY id
```

When you have more than just a few fixed items like `'p'` and `'c'` to aggregate, [pivoting](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) may provide a better option.

Answer (score 2):

Pivot solution. Works from sql-server 2008

```
declare @t table(id int, staus char(1))
insert @t values( 1,'p'),( 1,'p'),( 1,'c'),( 2,'p'),( 2,'c')

SELECT id, [p], [c] 
from @t
PIVOT
(count([staus])  
FOR staus
in([p],[c])  
)AS p
```

Result:

```
id  p  c
1   2  1
2   1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to do a pivot of your table, there is a simple article that I used when i faced your same problem [pivot table sql server](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx)